# php ksort trouble on 2 arrays merged

Tags: php, arrays, ksort

I have an issue with ksort function :

I create to arrays :

```php
foreach ($json2['ticket']['records'] as $item) {
    if ($item['externalId1'] == "325") {
        $subject = $item['subject'];
        $fields1[] = [ //this array must be created dynamic
            $item['insertDate'] => $subject . 'ticket',
        ];

    }
}

$query1204 = 'SELECT * FROM interventions where inter_clientid = "325"';
$result1204 = $db->query($query1204) or die($db->error);
while ($row1204 = $result1204->fetch_array()) {
    $fields2[] = [
        strtotime($row1204['inter_datedebprev']) * 1000 =>
            $row1204['inter_title'] . 'INTER',
    ];
}
```

And then I ksort a merged version of it

```
$final = array_merge($fields1,$fields2);
ksort($final);
$fild = json_encode($final);
print_r($fild);
```

The fact is arrays are sorted separately :

```
[
{
1559671503000: "Migration téléphonieticket"
 },
{
1559831744000: "Maintenanceticket"
},
{
1561723413000: "Renouvellement de postesticket"
},
{
1561743016000: "Migration vers Office 365ticket"
},
{
1562164271000: "ABO Office 365ticket"
},
{
1564221684000: "sdsfsdfticket"
},
{
1564728016000: "sdfsfticket"
},
{
 1564129800000: "Migration vers Office 365INTER"
},
{
 1564043400000: "Renouvellement de postesINTER"
 },
 {
 1564475400000: "Installation poste Maison AlfortINTER"
 },
 {
 1564644600000: "Installation copieur Maison AlfortINTER"
 }
```

What is wrong with it

The sorting features should apply on all datas together, not for each block

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give sample result that you're expecting?

Comment: please provide an array before merge and expected result, so others can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `ksort` will sort the keys of an array, since your array is multidimensional it is sorting the numeric indexes (i.e. is doing nothing). You will need to compare the keys of *each* array and for that you can use `usort` (I'm assuming you just want to order all items by date):

```
usort($final, function($a, $b) { return array_keys($a)[0] - array_keys($b)[0]; });
```